# Windows Phone 8 LayoutRoot DataContext "Parameter must be a valid index" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, intellisense

The XAML designer in Visual Studio 2012 seems to be giving a incorrect error when setting the DataContext of the LayoutRoot grid.

At the moment I have just been copying the "LongList" sample that can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PeopleHub-Windows-Phone-80-88abe94d) creates a list that looks like the list found in the peoples hub. The error is being called on this line of the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModels:PeopleViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}">
```

The entire DataContext attribute is underlined in blue with he Intellisense error "This parameter must be a valid index within the array. Parameter name: index"

The PeopleViewModel is simply a class copied straight from the sample. The code compiles fine, but the actual list isn't displaying in the designer at all (it's just invisible, but with the border outlines correctly positioned). Is there anyway to fix this issue? It's incredible irritating.

Many Thanks.

Comment: do you have the following namespace added to the xaml page? `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. It seems that the IsDesignTimeCreatableSetting=true 
means the code that sets the contents of the list must be fixed at compile time, if it can only fill the list at run-time (which mine does) it obviously won't display in the designer!

Answer (score 0):

This error appears due to an attempt to set the `SelectedItem` property of the `LongListSelector`, 
 to a value that is not a current member of the data-binded model of `ItemsSource` property.

The setting of the property can occur by user selection, by a trigger or by event.

In your case, you are setting design time data, using `d:DataContext`, to `PeopleViewModel.People`, 
 
You need to find out who is setting `SelectedItem` to invalid value.